# read text from textarea, modify text with ruby, and output modified text

Tags: ruby, textarea, sinatra

I'm trying to create a simple sinatra app with one page containing a text area with a submit button underneath. Below that is another textarea that displays the modified text from the first textarea after the submit button is clicked.

Sinatra is new to me, so this is the best I can come up with so far:

CH.erb

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>CH</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="main">
        <form action="" method="post">
            <textarea id="orig" rows="25" cols="150"></textarea>
            <br /><br /><br />
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
        <br /><br /><br />
        <textarea id="result" rows="25" cols="150"></textarea>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CH.rb

```
require 'sinatra'

get '/hi' do
  erb :CH
end

post '/hi' do
  # ????
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this for your response route:

```ruby
post '/hi' do
  @result = params['orig']
  erb :CH
end
```

and modify your view like so:

```html
<textarea id="result" rows="25" cols="150"><%=@result%></textarea>
```

*I personally advocate Haml over Erb, but to each his/her own.*

Comment: Thanks for the answer Phrogz. I copy/pasted your code, but unfortunately, both textareas are blank after clicking submit button. Any idea why? I'm not opposed to a Haml answer, i was just being lazy.

Comment: Whoops! You need `name="orig"` on your textarea, too.